# Unable to Access data from json object

Tags: json, r, dataframe, jsonlite, rjson

I have stored json data structure in a dataframe with single column, named **json_data** in R
so my json text is stored in this format

```
row 1)    { "results" : [ { "formatted_address" : "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, 
          Punjab, India", "types" : [ "route" ], "location" :"lat"31.1471305,"lng" 
          75.34121789999999 }, ]
row 2)     { "results" : [ { "formatted_address" : "SAS Nagar,  Chennai, India", 
       "types" : [ "route 2" ], "location" :"lat"30.67249,"lng" 23.988672537 ,}] 
row 3)   { "results" : [ { "formatted_address" : "Hind mata chowk, UP, India", 
       "types" : [ "route 4" ], "location" lat"48.973478983,"lng"64.982486763},] 
row 4)
row 5)
.
.
.
.row 1000)
```

What I want to achieve is want to access from each row formatted address, lat, lng from location and save them into three different columns such that

```
formatted_add                                       lat            lng
Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar,Punjab, India      31.1471305       75.34121789999999
SAS Nagar,  Chennai, India                    30.67249         23.988672537
Hind mata chowk, UP, India                    48.973478983     64.982486763
```

json_data_df is the name of dataframe

I'm trying to do

```
formatted_add=json_data_df$json_data$formatted_address
lat=json_data_df$json_data$formatted_address$geometry$location$lat
lng=json_data_df$json_data$formatted_address$geometry$location$lng
```

please see the O/P of dput() which I have pasted the sample row, from that row I want to access the first occurrence of **"formatted_address"** and its **"lat","lng"** under **location**. But this doesn't give me the output, any suggestions on what changes should be made. Thanks in advance

edit:

dput(head(json_data_df,1))

O\P

```
    {
        "results": [{
            "address_components": [{
                "long_name": "Unnamed Road",
                "short_name": "Unnamed Road",
                "types": ["route"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar",
                "short_name": "SAS Nagar",
                "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "Punjab",
                "short_name": "PB",
                "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "India",
                "short_name": "IN",
                "types": ["country", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "160003",
                "short_name": "160003",
                "types": ["postal_code"]
            }],
            "formatted_address": "Unnamed Road, Punjab 160003, India",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.6593213,
                        "lng": 76.7952105
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.6548837,
                        "lng": 76.7931289
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 30.6576094,
                    "lng": 76.794392
                },
                "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.6593213,
                        "lng": 76.79551868029151
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.6548837,
                        "lng": 76.7928207197085
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJYWQws23rDzkRsqz31TNCwXg",
            "types": ["route"]
        }, {
            "address_components": [{
                "long_name": "Bhabat",
                "short_name": "Bhabat",
                "types": ["locality", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar",
                "short_name": "SAS Nagar",
                "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "Punjab",
                "short_name": "PB",
                "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "India",
                "short_name": "IN",
                "types": ["country", "political"]
            }],
            "formatted_address": "Bhabat, Punjab, India",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.67249,
                        "lng": 76.81895999999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.64508,
                        "lng": 76.79106999999999
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 30.6575248,
                    "lng": 76.8057776
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.67249,
                        "lng": 76.81895999999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.64508,
                        "lng": 76.79106999999999
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJN3sGJEHrDzkRwGZ1GMXBa2Q",
            "types": ["locality", "political"]
        }, {
            "address_components": [{
                "long_name": "Chandigarh Airport Area",
                "short_name": "Chandigarh Airport Area",
                "types": ["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "Chandigarh",
                "short_name": "Chandigarh",
                "types": ["locality", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "Chandigarh",
                "short_name": "CH",
                "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "India",
                "short_name": "IN",
                "types": ["country", "political"]
            }],
            "formatted_address": "Chandigarh Airport Area, Chandigarh, India",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.696639,
                        "lng": 76.81389089999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.6568821,
                        "lng": 76.76542999999999
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 30.6783321,
                    "lng": 76.7884713
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.696639,
                        "lng": 76.81389089999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.6568821,
                        "lng": 76.76542999999999
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJcb4-lILsDzkRJIQJTpsMm8w",
            "types": ["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"]
        }, {
            "address_components": [{
                "long_name": "160004",
                "short_name": "160004",
                "types": ["postal_code"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "India",
                "short_name": "IN",
                "types": ["country", "political"]
            }],
            "formatted_address": "160004, India",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.6832516,
                        "lng": 76.8121771
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.6447985,
                        "lng": 76.7639648
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 30.6582706,
                    "lng": 76.7855866
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.6832516,
                        "lng": 76.8121771
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.6447985,
                        "lng": 76.7639648
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJf560w6fsDzkRXLKn0s52kHM",
            "types": ["postal_code"]
        }, {
            "address_components": [{
                "long_name": "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar",
                "short_name": "SAS Nagar",
                "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "Punjab",
                "short_name": "PB",
                "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "India",
                "short_name": "IN",
                "types": ["country", "political"]
            }],
            "formatted_address": "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.9369199,
                        "lng": 76.9439199
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.35902,
                        "lng": 76.52444009999999
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 30.6496486,
                    "lng": 76.7567368
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 30.9369199,
                        "lng": 76.9439199
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 30.35902,
                        "lng": 76.52444009999999
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJOyhuuFPlDzkRzrRj0bvdZPw",
            "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
        }, {
            "address_components": [{
                "long_name": "Punjab",
                "short_name": "PB",
                "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
            }, {
                "long_name": "India",
                "short_name": "IN",
                "types": ["country", "political"]
            }],
            "formatted_address": "Punjab, India",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 32.4994008,
                        "lng": 76.92175809999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 29.537147,
                        "lng": 73.88057999999999
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 31.1471305,
                    "lng": 75.34121789999999
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 32.4994008,
                        "lng": 76.92175809999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 29.537147,
                        "lng": 73.88057999999999
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJVXOeVqpkGTkRYYijAzEmvY8",
            "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
        }, {
            "address_components": [{
                "long_name": "India",
                "short_name": "IN",
                "types": ["country", "political"]
            }],
            "formatted_address": "India",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 35.5087008,
                        "lng": 97.39535869999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 6.4626999,
                        "lng": 68.1097
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 20.593684,
                    "lng": 78.96288
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 35.5087008,
                        "lng": 97.39498069999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 6.7535159,
                        "lng": 68.16288519999999
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
            "types": ["country", "political"]
        }],
        "status": "OK"
    }

row 2)
      {    "results" : [       {          "address_components" : [             {                "long_name" : "Unnamed Road",                "short_name" : "Unnamed Road",                "types" : [ "route" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Godown Area",                "short_name" : "Godown Area",                "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Chandigarh Airport Area",                "short_name" : "Chandigarh Airport Area",                "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Chandigarh",                "short_name" : "Chandigarh",                "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar",                "short_name" : "SAS Nagar",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Chandigarh",                "short_name" : "CH",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "India",                "short_name" : "IN",                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "140604",                "short_name" : "140604",                "types" : [ "postal_code" ]             }          ],          "formatted_address" : "Unnamed Road, Godown Area, Chandigarh Airport Area, Chandigarh, 140604, India",          "geometry" : {             "bounds" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.6617314,                   "lng" : 76.81240459999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.6611368,                   "lng" : 76.8107763                }             },             "location" : {                "lat" : 30.66141159999999,                "lng" : 76.8115756             },             "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",             "viewport" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.66278308029149,                   "lng" : 76.81293943029151                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.66008511970849,                   "lng" : 76.81024146970849                }             }          },          "place_id" : "ChIJBf4l00XrDzkRhE9fwLK7DNw",          "types" : [ "route" ]       },       {          "address_components" : [             {                "long_name" : "Bhabat",                "short_name" : "Bhabat",                "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar",                "short_name" : "SAS Nagar",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Punjab",                "short_name" : "PB",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "India",                "short_name" : "IN",                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]             }          ],          "formatted_address" : "Bhabat, Punjab, India",          "geometry" : {             "bounds" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.67249,                   "lng" : 76.81895999999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.64508,                   "lng" : 76.79106999999999                }             },             "location" : {                "lat" : 30.6575248,                "lng" : 76.8057776             },             "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",             "viewport" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.67249,                   "lng" : 76.81895999999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.64508,                   "lng" : 76.79106999999999                }             }          },          "place_id" : "ChIJN3sGJEHrDzkRwGZ1GMXBa2Q",          "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]       },       {          "address_components" : [             {                "long_name" : "Chandigarh Airport Area",                "short_name" : "Chandigarh Airport Area",                "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Chandigarh",                "short_name" : "Chandigarh",                "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Chandigarh",                "short_name" : "CH",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "India",                "short_name" : "IN",                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]             }          ],          "formatted_address" : "Chandigarh Airport Area, Chandigarh, India",          "geometry" : {             "bounds" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.696639,                   "lng" : 76.81389089999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.6568821,                   "lng" : 76.76542999999999                }             },             "location" : {                "lat" : 30.6783321,                "lng" : 76.7884713             },             "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",             "viewport" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.696639,                   "lng" : 76.81389089999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.6568821,                   "lng" : 76.76542999999999                }             }          },          "place_id" : "ChIJcb4-lILsDzkRJIQJTpsMm8w",          "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]       },       {          "address_components" : [             {                "long_name" : "140604",                "short_name" : "140604",                "types" : [ "postal_code" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Punjab",                "short_name" : "PB",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "India",                "short_name" : "IN",                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]             }          ],          "formatted_address" : "Punjab 140604, India",          "geometry" : {             "bounds" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.6698436,                   "lng" : 76.8210886                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.6552941,                   "lng" : 76.80184109999999                }             },             "location" : {                "lat" : 30.6625018,                "lng" : 76.8129878             },             "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",             "viewport" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.6698436,                   "lng" : 76.8210886                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.6552941,                   "lng" : 76.80184109999999                }             }          },          "place_id" : "ChIJpzrfc1DrDzkRc_qbC2Hz3tc",          "types" : [ "postal_code" ]       },       {          "address_components" : [             {                "long_name" : "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar",                "short_name" : "SAS Nagar",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "Punjab",                "short_name" : "PB",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "India",                "short_name" : "IN",                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]             }          ],          "formatted_address" : "Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India",          "geometry" : {             "bounds" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.9369199,                   "lng" : 76.9439199                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.35902,                   "lng" : 76.52444009999999                }             },             "location" : {                "lat" : 30.6496486,                "lng" : 76.7567368             },             "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",             "viewport" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 30.9369199,                   "lng" : 76.9439199                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 30.35902,                   "lng" : 76.52444009999999                }             }          },          "place_id" : "ChIJOyhuuFPlDzkRzrRj0bvdZPw",          "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]       },       {          "address_components" : [             {                "long_name" : "Punjab",                "short_name" : "PB",                "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]             },             {                "long_name" : "India",                "short_name" : "IN",                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]             }          ],          "formatted_address" : "Punjab, India",          "geometry" : {             "bounds" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 32.4994008,                   "lng" : 76.92175809999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 29.537147,                   "lng" : 73.88057999999999                }             },             "location" : {                "lat" : 31.1471305,                "lng" : 75.34121789999999             },             "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",             "viewport" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 32.4994008,                   "lng" : 76.92175809999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 29.537147,                   "lng" : 73.88057999999999                }             }          },          "place_id" : "ChIJVXOeVqpkGTkRYYijAzEmvY8",          "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]       },       {          "address_components" : [             {                "long_name" : "India",                "short_name" : "IN",                "types" : [ "country", "political" ]             }          ],          "formatted_address" : "India",          "geometry" : {             "bounds" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 35.5087008,                   "lng" : 97.39535869999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 6.4626999,                   "lng" : 68.1097                }             },             "location" : {                "lat" : 20.593684,                "lng" : 78.96288             },             "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",             "viewport" : {                "northeast" : {                   "lat" : 35.5087008,                   "lng" : 97.39498069999999                },                "southwest" : {                   "lat" : 6.7535159,                   "lng" : 68.16288519999999                }             }          },          "place_id" : "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",          "types" : [ "country", "political" ]       }    ],    "status" : "OK" }
```

Comment: Can you share some data using dput(). When reading/writing in a json file use `simplifyVector = TRUE` to get a readable data.frame

Comment: @timfaber have reproduced only one record of dataframe..because as you can see that quite a big json

Comment: to clarify: you have a JSON object per each row of your data.frame?

Comment: Yes I have JSON Object per each row of my dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after the clarification, what you have is a JSON string per each row of the data.frame

To recreate the data, I'm taking the single JSON string (row) you provided, and putting it in two rows of a data.frame

Therefore, to access the data, you need to parse each row of the data.frame individually

However, in your question, you ask for the "**first occurrence** of `formatted_address` under location". 
In the row of data you've given, there are seven different locations, which you can see by the number of `place_id` values, and there is only one `formatted_address` per `place_id`.
So asking for the **first occurrence** doesn't make sense, as there is only one.

```
library(jsonlite)

js <- '{
                 "results": [{
                       "address_components": [{
                       "long_name": "Unnamed Road",
                       "short_name": "Unnamed Road",
                       "types": ["route"]
                       }, {
                       .... <i've omitted the rest of the text> ...
                       },
                       "place_id": "ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
                        "types": ["country", "political"]
                       }],
                        "status": "OK"
                       }'

json_data_df <- data.frame(json_data = c(js, js))

## if parsing a row individually you would do
# json_result <- fromJSON(as.character(json_data_df[1, "json_data"]))

## as you're parsing each row of the data.frame, you can use whatever looping 
## method you like

## you can get all the data out of the JSON and create a list obect of everything
lst <- lapply(1:nrow(json_data_df), function(x){
  fromJSON(as.character(json_data_df[x, 'json_data']))
})


## or you can subset it within the loop to just get the bits you want
lst <- lapply(1:nrow(json_data_df), function(x){
  js <- fromJSON(as.character(json_data_df[x, 'json_data']))
  data.frame(
    place_id = js$results$place_id,
    formatted_address = js$results$formatted_address,
    lat = js$results$geometry$location$lat,
    lng = js$results$geometry$location$lng
    )
})

lst
# [[1]]
#                      place_id                          formatted_address      lat      lng
# 1 ChIJYWQws23rDzkRsqz31TNCwXg         Unnamed Road, Punjab 160003, India 30.65761 76.79439
# 2 ChIJN3sGJEHrDzkRwGZ1GMXBa2Q                      Bhabat, Punjab, India 30.65752 76.80578
# 3 ChIJcb4-lILsDzkRJIQJTpsMm8w Chandigarh Airport Area, Chandigarh, India 30.67833 76.78847
# 4 ChIJf560w6fsDzkRXLKn0s52kHM                              160004, India 30.65827 76.78559
# 5 ChIJOyhuuFPlDzkRzrRj0bvdZPw  Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India 30.64965 76.75674
# 6 ChIJVXOeVqpkGTkRYYijAzEmvY8                              Punjab, India 31.14713 75.34122
# 7 ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc                                      India 20.59368 78.96288
# 
# [[2]]
#                      place_id                          formatted_address      lat      lng
# 1 ChIJYWQws23rDzkRsqz31TNCwXg         Unnamed Road, Punjab 160003, India 30.65761 76.79439
# 2 ChIJN3sGJEHrDzkRwGZ1GMXBa2Q                      Bhabat, Punjab, India 30.65752 76.80578
# 3 ChIJcb4-lILsDzkRJIQJTpsMm8w Chandigarh Airport Area, Chandigarh, India 30.67833 76.78847
# 4 ChIJf560w6fsDzkRXLKn0s52kHM                              160004, India 30.65827 76.78559
# 5 ChIJOyhuuFPlDzkRzrRj0bvdZPw  Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India 30.64965 76.75674
# 6 ChIJVXOeVqpkGTkRYYijAzEmvY8                              Punjab, India 31.14713 75.34122
# 7 ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc                                      India 20.59368 78.96288
```

---

As per the comments - to access just the first entry per each JSON object, you can just subset the first element in the `lapply`

```
## or you can subset it within the loop to just get the bits you want
lst <- lapply(1:nrow(json_data_df), function(x){
  js <- fromJSON(as.character(json_data_df[x, 'json_data']))
  data.frame(
    place_id = js$results$place_id[1],
    formatted_address = js$results$formatted_address[1],
    lat = js$results$geometry$location$lat[1],
    lng = js$results$geometry$location$lng[1]
  )
})
lst

# [[1]]
#                      place_id                  formatted_address      lat      lng
# 1 ChIJYWQws23rDzkRsqz31TNCwXg Unnamed Road, Punjab 160003, India 30.65761 76.79439

# [[2]]
#                      place_id                  formatted_address      lat      lng
# 1 ChIJYWQws23rDzkRsqz31TNCwXg Unnamed Road, Punjab 160003, India 30.65761 76.79439
```

Comment: your first approach(reading json data as dataframe) works fine with only one record, if I run it on entire data set it gives me error "Error: parse error: trailing garbage
          }    ],    "status" : "OK" } {    "results" : [       {     
                     (right here) ------^"

Comment: Next thing I request you to go through my post again because what I want is the record of first occurrence of  "formatted_address" and its "lat", and "lng".

Comment: And last thing if I go by your next approach i.e by reading data through .json file doing this --->  json_data$results$formatted_address..   gives error :: Error in json_data$results : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors :: class(json_data) =  "character"

Comment: 1. It sounds like your JSON is not formatted correctly. 2. There's no mention of 'first occurrence' in your question - maybe you need to edit it to clarify your requirements? 3. On the data you've provided, these methods work. To see exactly your error you need to generate an example data set that demonstrates your errors. Lastly, the data comes from Google Places API?  [maybe there are other ways you can get the data](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+google_places)

Comment: The point is that all those seven different location belong to one row of a dataframe; and second row of data frame consist of other seven different location. thats the reason why I said first occurrence of "formatted address". As you can see the sample row 2) it contains seven different "formatted address", of which I want to access its first occurrence and its "lat" and "lng" under geometry -->location.

Comment: "json_data_df <- data.frame(json_data = c(js, js))"  what is "js" here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145762/discussion-between-deepesh-and-symbolixau).

Comment: Finally,, It worked with this code "lst <- lapply(1:nrow(json_data_df), function(x){
  js <- fromJSON(as.character(json_data_df[x, 'json_data']))
  data.frame(
    place_id = js$results$place_id[1],
    formatted_address = js$results$formatted_address[1],
    lat = js$results$geometry$location$lat[1],
    lng = js$results$geometry$location$lng[1]
  )
})"..................................Thanks a tonn... It really saved my day.. :)     Thanks for the effort!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility:

```
library(rjson)

json_data <- fromJSON(file = json_file)
formatted_add <- lapply(json_data$results, function(x) x$formatted_add)
lat <- lapply(json_data$results, function(x) x$geometry$location$lat)
lng <- lapply(json_data$results, function(x) x$geometry$location$lng)

data <- cbind(formatted_add, lat, lng)
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: your code gets executed but the output object have nothing, it shows "List of 0".. Why so

Comment: have you added the path to your json_file? `json_file <- "path/to/your/file.json"`

Comment: Yes I had added the path to my .json file

Comment: does `lapply(json_data$results, function(x) x)` give you any result? I copied your `dput(head(json_data_df,1))` output to a file, so maybe your actual total structure has another level?

Comment: No that still gives me "list of 0"

Comment: what does `names(json_data)` result in? Did the command `fromJSON` work?

Comment: names(json_data) gives me NULL,, and command fromJSON is being used for reading json file from path

Comment: NO...including these two library didn't helped